# Scaffold-DbContext Fails. System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.ProductInfo' on .NET Core

Tags: c#, oracle, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have just created an ASP .NET Core 3.1 API Web Application and would like to generate 'DbContext' files from my Oracle database. I am disappointed to find out that there seems to be no visual designer built in like there is in .NET Standard.

What I have tried:

- Created .NET Core 3.1 API Web Application.
- Installed the following NuGet  packages:

  - Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 3.1.2;
  - Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design 2.2.6;
  - Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational 2.2.6;
  - Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.Design 1.1.6
  - Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 2.2.6;
  - Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore 2.19.6;
  - Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core 2.19.6;

I then tried calling the `Scaffold-DbContext` command on the package manager console:

`Scaffold-DbContext "DATA SOURCE=(DESCRIPTION=(SOURCE_ROUTE=OFF)(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=myHostName)(PORT=myPortNumber)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=mySID)(SERVER=DEDICATED))); User ID=myID;Password=myPassword;" Oracle.ManagedDataAccess -OutputDir Models -Tables myTableName`

With this command, I was hoping a db context class would be generated for my table, however, the following error is returned instead:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
 ---> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.ProductInfo' from assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=3.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor..ctor(Object reportHandler, IDictionary args)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Object[] args)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.ReflectionOperationExecutor..ctor(String assembly, String startupAssembly, String projectDir, String dataDirectory, String rootNamespace, String language)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Commands.ProjectCommandBase.CreateExecutor()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Commands.DbContextScaffoldCommand.Execute()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Commands.CommandBase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0()
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.CommandLine.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Program.Main(String[] args)
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
```

Answer (score 3):

Solved in two steps:

1. All entity framework and Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design packages must be at the same version level, e.g. v3.1 below

   ```
     <PropertyGroup>
       <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
       <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
     </PropertyGroup>

     <ItemGroup>
       <PackageReference Include="Hangfire" Version="1.7.11" />
       <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1" />
       <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1" />
       <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.1" />
       <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="3.1" />
     </ItemGroup>
   </Project>
   ```
2. Given the above, the TypeLoadException should go away, possibly replaced by an *Instance Failure* error, say if you are using the same connection string that your project uses.  Solve the *Instance Failure* by using SINGLE backslashes in your connection string rather than the usual double:

WRONG WAY:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=DESKTOP-C2IEMCJ\\MSSQLSERVER17;Database=HangFire01;Trusted_Connection=True" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```

RIGHT WAY - Notice the SINGLE slash right before MSSQLSERVER17 below:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=DESKTOP-C2IEMCJ\MSSQLSERVER17;Database=HangFire01;Trusted_Connection=True" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```

Comment: Had problems after Nuget Updates. _packages must be at the same version level_ did it for me. Thanks.

Comment: Had the same issue. And packages being on the same level solved it.
However, in my case, I had a DAL project separate from the main web project but the packages on the projects were on different levels.